# How to check whether my two pubkeyHash is different or not using Haskell?

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, haskell, minting

I'm using this script to check but this doesn't works for me

```
import    Prelude  hiding (Eq)

mkPolicy :: PubKeyHash -> PubKeyHash -> TokenName -> BuiltinData -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkPolicy owner1 owner2 name _redeemer ctx = checkOwnerHashDifferent

    checkOwnerHashDifferent :: Bool
    checkOwnerHashDifferent =  Eq owner1 owner2
```

can someone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Eq` is a type class and hence will not work as you have used it above.

Assuming that `PubKeyHash` has an `Eq` typeclass instance you just need:

```
    checkOwnerHashDifferent :: Bool
    checkOwnerHashDifferent =  owner1 == owner2
```